# Marking fields in forms : like (*) asterisk for mandatory field

Tags: html, winforms, forms, standards

Is there a standard way of marking a field mandatory in forms (Web/Windows).

Marking the label with *(asterisk) is one standard.

What are the standards available?

In case of radio buttons, list box, checkboxes how is this done?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standards. I would suggest you take a look at several large sites (Google, Facebook, SO, ...), see how they do it and use the one that you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standards. It's a matter of Usability - Users are used to the fact that required fields are marked somehow. Sometimes you have a `*` marking the mandatory fields, sometimes it's vice versa.

You go best by marking them e.g. with a `*` and add a note `* these fields are required`. In the end doing it according to the majority of the websites and the most influental ones (facebook,google) is porobably a good choice.

You can do this for all types of inputs regardless of it being an input field or a checkbox or radio button.